# LAMMPS: How to enter a simple potential for Dissipative Particle Dynamics (DPD)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, software, molecular-dynamics

I apologize if this is off-topic and if so would be grateful for someone to point me to a relevant source of information.

Dissipative Particle Dynamics (DPD) is a quick simulation technique that clumps molecules in a fluid into "beads" of similar size that interact only through short range repulsive forces.  I want to introduce a polymer chain into the fluid simulation so I need tell the DPD package in LAMMPS that there is a specific (simple) potential between the "beads" that chain together to form the polymer. (Eventually we may make membranes as well).

The potentials that I can find on the LAMMPS site are for specific atoms, or contain too much physics for the simple  beads-in-a-chain model I am trying to construct.  Is there a package or way to enter simple potentials for DPD?

Comment: The Matter Modeling SE folks might have more info over there...

Comment: This seems awfully specific to LAMMPS, which probably means it should be asked at [their user forum](https://www.lammps.org/forum.html) (which redirects to [this page](https://matsci.org)).

Comment: I appreciate the redirect. Is it ok to leave this here so anyone who has a similar question can follow the trail?